# Search and replace rows of a data frame in R

Tags: r

```
  search <- function(x,max_hp){
  count <- 1
  result <- matrix(NA, nrow =nrow(x), ncol = ncol(x))
  for(i in 1:nrow(x)){
    temp_row <- x[i,]
    if(temp_row[4] < max_hp){
      result[count,] <- temp_row
      count <- count + 1
    }
  }
  return(result)
}
```

I want to search the rows of `mtcars` data frame in R that have `hp > 240`
 using a for loop (iterating over each row of the data frame) and then, return only the ones that match. But, my code doesn't work. I want to store each matched row in an empty matrix.

Comment: mtcars[mtcars$hp > 240,] -> result.

Comment: Is this a mooc assignment? Doing this with a for loop and storing in a matrix is a bit of a tedious way to do it when you could just subset it: `result <- mtcars[mtcars$hp > 240,]`

Comment: Yes, its tough! but, what I don't understand is why R complains  when I try to substitute a row with another row:

Answer (score 1):

I have too few points to comment but I have a couple points to share.  First, I agree with @Otto Kässi or @seeellayewhy.  I would just add that if you don't whant any NAs in mtcars$hp to remain in your result, you need to use

```
result <- mtcars[which(mtcars$hp > 240),]
```

Regarding substituting rows, I would just follow the above command with

```
result <- rbind(result,newrows)
```

R will complain if any attributes of the columns in newrows are different than in result, especially if any of your columns are factor data types with any difference in the levels defined.